# How do I change the symbols of the plot created by this function?

Tags: r

How do I change the symbols in this plot created by a for loop?

```
colors.use = rainbow(nlevels(fish$Region))
for (i in 1:nlevels(fish$Region)) {
  predictions = predict(g1, type="response", newdata = data.frame(Distance= 1000, A.Depth = seq(0,3000,length=1000), Region = levels(fish$Region)[i]))
  if (i == 1) plot(seq(0,3000,length=1000), predictions, type = 'l', col=colors.use[i])
if (i > 1) lines(seq(0,3000,length=1000), predictions,col=colors.use[i])
}
```

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: ` .......col = colors.use[i], pch = i)` is worth a try